# Site login using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL for the first time. I need to login to a site and my code is not working.
help.

i have problem whit setting cookie

```
<?php

$cookie_file_path = tempnam('/tmp', 'cookie');

// Login variables
$urls = 'http://mypage.php';
$uname = 'user';
$upass = 'pass';
$unamefield = '*****';
$upassfield = '*****';
$usubmit = 'submit';

// Log into the specified website and return the cURL variable
function login($loginURL, $username, $userFieldName, $password, $passFieldName, $usubmitContent)  {
        // Initialize the page
        $page = curl_init($loginURL);
        // Set POST data
        curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $postData = $userFieldName . '=' . $username . '&' . $passFieldName . '=' . $password;
        if(!empty($usubmitContent))       $postData = $postData . '&' . $usubmitContent;

        curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($page,      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Set the location of and send the cookies
        curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

        // return the cURL variable for later use
        return $page;
}

$page = login($urls, $unamefield, $uname, $upassfield, $upass, $usubmit);
$result = curl_exec($page);

// curl_close($page);

print $result;

$page = curl_init('http://mypage.php');
// Set the location of and send the cookies
curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec($page);
curl_close($page);

print $result;
?>
```

i google it to see what is the problem and no luck.

Comment: Please show us some more code and some error messages.  Be sure to put your code within the code tags when you post.

Answer (score 0):

Per your Login variables at the top, it looks like you have your name and password variables incorrectly defined.  Shouldn't it be:

```
// Login variables
$urls = 'http://mypage.php';
$unamefield = 'user';
$upassfield = 'pass';
$uname= '*****';
$upass= '*****';
$usubmit = 'submit';
```

Your code seems to work fine up to the first `print $result;`.  What is the remaining code there for (i.e. the second curl_init)?  Also, use an absolute path to the cookie file.  In your login function, do something like this:

```
$cookie_file = "/tmp/cookies.txt";
curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
```

Comment: If i change it the COOKIEJAR to $cookie_file like u sugested it gives
Undefined variable: cookie_file_path  error.

Comment: Are you in a Windows machine? That `/tmp/...` path is for Unix/Linux hosts.